# While Reverse String Loop

Tags: loops, while-loop

```
def reverse(x):
    word = ""
    b = len(x)
    while b >= 0:

        word = word + x[b:]
        b = b - 1
    print word
```

Was trying to make reverse function, when input "why" outputs

```
yhywhy
```

Why?

Comment: ?thgir, "Why?" naem ouY ... _"?yhW"_ :eR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
b = len(x)
```

To this:

```
b = len(x)-1
```

And this:

```
x[b:]
```

To this:

```
x[b]
```

---

A more "pythonic" way of doing it:

```
def reverse(x):
    print ''.join([x[i] for i in range(len(x)-1,-1,-1)])
```

Comment: Could you explain this loop in greater detail?  What do the [x[i] signify at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Your slice was reading from the index to end of string

try

```
def reverse(x):
    word = ""
    b = len(x)-1
    while b >= 0:
        word += x[b]
        b -= 1
    print word
```